# confusion regarding "imresize" in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have read on below weblink that the "imresize" command can be used to change resolution of an image? Is it true? Because apparently keyword "imresize" suggests change of size?

Does this size means storage( Kbs size) or display size?

https://www.electronicsforu.com/electronics-projects/software-projects-ideas/image-processing-using-matlab-basic-operations-part-2-4

Comment: things are related. However, I cannot understand exactly what you are asking. Can you try to re-write, please? I suggest the use of Grammarly. I am not going to edit for the same reason.

Comment: Why would it be false? Also, the documentation is super clear about what it does, it even has examples

Comment: "Because apparently keyword suggests change of size?" -> I cannot understand the meaning. Even changing "because" with "why".

Comment: `imresize` can reduce the resolution of the image, if you "zoom out". But you can not increase the resolution of the image, only the sampling density (which also increases the size). The resolution is related to the smallest detail you can see in the image. Increasing the size by interpolation doesn't add detail to the image, hence the resolution remains unchanged.

Comment: @CrisLuengo sampling density? DPI?

Comment: Yes, the number of samples per unit length. DPI if you're into photography, micron per pixel if you're into microscopy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be cautious in saying that `imresize` can change the resolution. It depends on how you define resolution but the way that I define image resolution is that resolution is the ability to distinguish between two neighboring fine objects in the image. This can be determined by for example calculating the FWHM of the profile of a very thin line, or a point, taken in your image. `imresize` changes the number of pixels and pixel density of the image but can it actually separate two objects from each other if they are indistinguishable in the original image? While you can **sharpen** the image by using `imresize` I think you cannot enhance the resolution of an image with it. Let's say I have a sharp "high resolution" image of a bird taken with a high resolution camera like this:

[image: Original image]

This image has 400 x 400 pixels. So if it has 3 bytes per pixel, this image's size is 3x400x400 bytes (468.75 KB). Now I downsample the image by `im_downsampled = imresize(im, 0.1)` such that the resulting image would have 40 x 40 pixels (image size 40x40x3 bytes or ~4.7 KB) like this

[image: Original image downsampled]

The resulting image is blurred and the size has been reduced. Now can I recover the image to its original *resolution* by doing `im_upsampled = imresize(im_downsampled, 10)`? Well, let's see:

[image: Recovered image]

As you can see while the image looks smoother, fine structures cannot be recovered. The resulting image `im_upsampled` has **the same size** as the original image (400x400x3 bytes), however the resolution has already been missed. I hope that the file sizes I mentioned clarify the confusion on image KB size.

Comment: Nice explaination, do you mean,we can only reduce resolution using imresize but we cannot use imresize for increasing resolution?

Comment: Correct. You can only increase the pixel elements by `imresize` not spatial resolution.

Comment: but what then is the command for increasing image resolution?

Comment: You could upsample your image and apply a filter so that your image looks **sharper** but I am not aware of any methods that can actually increase image resolution.